# How do I convert temp from Celsius to Fahrenheit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, weather

Almost done with my weather app just having trouble converting my temp from Celsius to Fahrenheit. I made a button and used an event handler to see if it works but when I fetch a city's api it shows both conversion. Also when I press the conversion button it makes the Fahrenheit disappear (honestly would like this to happen but in reverse, so it pops up on click). This is honestly the last thing I need done.

**App.js:**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Greeting from "./Greeting";

const API_key = "dsdfghjkjhgfd";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      city: "",
      country: undefined,
      weather: "",
      temp: "",
      fahr: true,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleConvert = this.handleConvert.bind(this);
    this.newTemp = this.newTemp.bind(this);
  }

  newTemp(temp) {
    let cell = Math.floor((temp * 9) / 5) + 32;
    return cell;
  }

  calCelsius(temp) {
    let cell = Math.floor(temp);
    return cell;
  }

  /*shouldComponentUpdate() {
        this.handleConvert();
    
    }*/

  handleConvert() {
    const { fahr } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      fahr: true,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleConvert();
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    this.setState({ [name]: value });

    this.handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const city = event.target.value;
      fetch(
        `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${API_key}`
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.setState({
            city: `${response.name}`,
            country: `${response.sys.country}`,
            temp: this.calCelsius(`${response.main.temp}`),
            fahr: this.newTemp(`${response.main.temp}`),
            weather: `${response.weather[0].main}`,
          });
        });
    };
  }

  render() {
    let date = String(new window.Date());
    date = date.slice(0, 15);

    return (
      <div
        className={
          typeof this.state.weather != "undefined"
            ? this.state.temp > 16
              ? "app hot"
              : "app"
            : "app"
        }
      >
        <main>
          <div className="search-box">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="search-bar"
                placeholder="Enter a city"
                name="city"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.value}
              />
            </form>
          </div>

          <div>
            <div className="location-box">
              <div className="location">
                {this.state.city},{this.state.country}{" "}
              </div>
              <div className="date">{date}</div>
              <div className="greet">
                <Greeting />
              </div>
              <div className="weather-box">
                <div className="temp">{this.state.temp}°C</div>
                <div className="fahr">{this.state.fahr}°F</div>
                <div className="weather">{this.state.weather}</div>
                <button onClick={this.handleConvert}>Convert Temp</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any celsius value to fahrenheit by multiplying it with 9/5 and adding 32.

Example:

```
function convertToF(celsius) {
  return celsius * 9/5 + 32
}

convertToF(30); // 86
```

Comment: I already did that but I just want the button to pop up the handle that shows newTemp() handler. Right now when I fetch the data it shows both temps. I want only Celsius then when I press button the Fahrenheit pops up.

Answer (score 0):

0C is 32F, and the scale is 5/9th, so it goes Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9

```
const celsius = -23;
const fahrenheit = 113;

const celsiusDegree = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
console.log(celsiusDegree); //-9.4

const fahrenheitDegree = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
console.log(fahrenheitDegree); //45
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.